# File sharing to multiple users with different permissions

Tags: permissions, ssh

I have a file server used to backup network configs.

I have 5 admins

I have 6 users

Everyone needs access to all files.

Admins need all permissions

Users need permissions read, copy and edit copy

Basically all I need is to be able to ssh to the server.

Could someone please help as everything I read just deals with home accounts.

Comment: I also need for the network devices to send their configs to the server.

Comment: Welcome! There is no difference between ssh to a server or a desktop os. Same goes  for file permissions. What exactly were you struggling with? Also: what type of file server is it? smb? nfs? ftp? What os runs it, and what os are your clients running? Please edit your question with more information provided.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please see the [overview tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help) for what type of questions are suitable for this site. Your question is too broad. I suggest you start with the first admin and try to get everything done one step at a time. Search here if you get stuck. If you find no answers ask a question.